Do Spring Cloud Gateway MVC requires at least JRE JDK 21?
Do Spring Cloud Gateway MVC requires at least JDK/JRE 21 or can it run on older versions such as JDK/JRE 17, 11, 8?

Spring Cloud Gateway can run on older Java versions like JDK 17, 11, or 8. However, if you're using a newer Spring Boot, you'll need a newer Java version.
Newer Java versions are better for performance and security, so upgrade if possible.

How about the newest Spring Cloud Gateway MVC? It relies on Java's Virtual Threads which are "stable" in JDK/JRE 21. Or can it be used without virtual threads?

The latest Spring Cloud Gateway MVC can use Virtual Threads, which are only in JDK 21. It’ll still work on older versions like JDK 17, 11, or 8, but you won’t get those new benefits. Upgrading to JDK 21 is a good move if you can.

Understood: "can use", but not "need to use"

Can you please update your answer with this new info? because it looks like you are writing about spring cloud gateway reactive and not mvc
